# Compiling for Android on Android

Tags: android, compilation, theory

This is more of a theoretical questions, one which I may not have thought through properly, but is it POSSIBLE to compile an Android app ON an Android device?
As in, write up the sourcecode on the device, compile, test and deploy it, without having to use an other OS for any part of the process?

Comment: of course. however, there is no trivial way to do this as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, yes. In practice, this is a lot of work. Compiling an android app involves a lot of separate tools, like the full-blown JDK, and a lot of other tools sign the resulting JAR and package it into an APK. That would have to be ported to Android, which is a major undertaking.

Comment: I'm sure somebody is crazy enough to try this sooner or later. Technically, a (rooted) tablet should have the necessary horsepower and RAM to do the trick. The only thing that would be pretty easy to do is a setup that sends the source to a server which compiles it and sends it back to you. Of course, that goes against what you're trying to do here, but from a usability perspective, it's the same thing. You're programming on your tablet without a workstation nearby.